# Determine upload_credential_id for custom buildfarm?

Tags: ros, buildfarm, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up a custom buildfarm for use with some private repos. My latest issue is I'm not sure what upload_credential_id should be in rosbuild_config/indigo/release-build.yaml. The [docs](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/master/doc/configuration_options.rst) aren't super helpful, "the ID of the credential to upload the built packages to the repository host". Which credential? How do I extract the ID?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210823/determine-upload_credential_id-for-custom-buildfarm?/) by [etappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22710/etappan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The credential_id is defined in the master deployment common.yaml

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment_config/blob/master/master/common.yaml#L14

This credential will be inserted into jenkins credential storage. (You can find the credentials via the Jenkins UI by clicking on "Credentials" at the top level, then "Global Credentials" in the Credentials page. Clicking on a specific credential you can find the ID in the url. I believe the ID is just a uuid.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-08**:
I added a some more comments in the documentation too.

**Comment by [etappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22710/etappan/) on 2015-06-09**:
Thanks for the response. So to clarify, all non-plaintext values in [ros_]buildfarm_[deployment_]config should be generated via a separate Jenkins instance before ever running the deployment scripts? And then the deployment scripts should configure the Master machine to serve a Jenkins instance.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-09**:
You can actually use the values in the example. They don't need to be generated. If you wanted to change them you would want to do it that way.